# Collection of StackPanes collision detection

Tags: java, javafx

I have a collection of shapes that I am trying to check for collision between each other, but I all I have achieved so far is detecting collisions between three nodes closest to each other.

The method addToRectCollection adds stack panes to the collection, onDragged males each shape draggable.

What should I change/add to detect collisions between all of the elements of the collection?

Below is my code:

```
public class CollisionDection extends Application {
    final ObjectProperty<Point2D> mousePosition = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
    Group gp = new Group();

    *I try to detect collisions between elements of this list*
    ArrayList<StackPane> stackPanes = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        Scene sc = new Scene(gp, 700, 300);

        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("CREATE REct");

        btn.setOnAction(event -> {
            Rectangle r = createRect(0);
            r.setFill(Color.RED);

            Text text = new Text(".");
            StackPane stack = new StackPane();

            StackPane.setMargin(r, new Insets(8, 8, 8, 8));
            stack.getChildren().addAll(r, text);

            ChoiceBox<String> dropdown = new ChoiceBox<>();
            stack.getChildren().add(dropdown);

            makeDraggable(stack);
            addToRectCollection(stack);

            gp.getChildren().add(stack);
        });

        gp.getChildren().add(btn);

        stage.setScene(sc);
        stage.show();
    }

    private void addToRectCollection(StackPane r) {
        stackPanes.add(r);
        stackPanes.forEach(rect -> {
            stackPanes.forEach(rect2 -> {
                if (!rect.equals(rect2)) {
                    setOnDragegd(rect2, rect);
                    setOnDragegd(rect, rect2);
                }
            });
        });
    }

    private void setOnDragegd(StackPane pane, StackPane paneToSetDragged) {
        paneToSetDragged.setOnMouseDragged((MouseEvent event) -> {
            double deltaX = event.getSceneX() - mousePosition.get().getX();
            double deltaY = event.getSceneY() - mousePosition.get().getY();
            paneToSetDragged.setLayoutX(paneToSetDragged.getLayoutX() + deltaX);
            paneToSetDragged.setLayoutY(paneToSetDragged.getLayoutY() + deltaY);
            mousePosition.set(new Point2D(event.getSceneX(), event.getSceneY()));

            var intersect = paneToSetDragged.getBoundsInParent().intersects(pane.getBoundsInParent());
            if (intersect) {

                pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #6a5246");
                paneToSetDragged.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #6a5246");

                Group g = new Group();
                g.getChildren().add(paneToSetDragged);
                g.getChildren().add(pane);
                gp.getChildren().add(g);

                paneToSetDragged.setLayoutX(paneToSetDragged.getLayoutX() - deltaX);
                paneToSetDragged.setLayoutY(paneToSetDragged.getLayoutY() - deltaY);
            } else {
                pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #ffffff");
                paneToSetDragged.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #ffffff");
            }
        });
    }

    private void makeDraggable(StackPane ractangleToSetDragged) {
        ractangleToSetDragged.setOnMousePressed((MouseEvent event) -> mousePosition.set(new Point2D(event.getSceneX(), event.getSceneY())));

        ractangleToSetDragged.setOnMouseDragged((MouseEvent event) -> {
            double deltaX = event.getSceneX() - mousePosition.get().getX();
            double deltaY = event.getSceneY() - mousePosition.get().getY();
            ractangleToSetDragged.setLayoutX(ractangleToSetDragged.getLayoutX() + deltaX);
            ractangleToSetDragged.setLayoutY(ractangleToSetDragged.getLayoutY() + deltaY);
            mousePosition.set(new Point2D(event.getSceneX(), event.getSceneY()));
        });
    }

    public Rectangle createRect(int x) {
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
        r.setX(x);
        r.setY(60);
        r.setWidth(300);
        r.setHeight(150);

        return r;
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to test for collision with *all* other panes in the handler for `StackPane.onMouseDragged`, for each pane you add to the collection.

What you're doing now is incorrect because you re-set the handler for each pane any time you add a new StackPane. That may work using `StackPane.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, ...)` instead of `StackPane.setOnMouseDragged(...)`, but it would be heavy, slow, and memory consuming, as it would potentially chain a large number of event handlers for each new StackPane.

As you've only got one moving pane at once (when it's being dragged), you'd rather set the `onMouseDragged` handler once for each new pane, and then inside this handler, loop through your `stackPanes` ArrayList to test for intersection with all other panes, which would change your code to something like this:

```java
private void addToRectCollection(StackPane r) {
  stackPanes.add(r);
  r.setOnMouseDragged((MouseEvent event) -> {
    double deltaX = event.getSceneX() - mousePosition.get().getX();
    double deltaY = event.getSceneY() - mousePosition.get().getY();
    r.setLayoutX(r.getLayoutX() + deltaX);
    r.setLayoutY(r.getLayoutY() + deltaY);
    mousePosition.set(new Point2D(event.getSceneX(), event.getSceneY()));
    //Test collision for this pane with all other ones
    testCollision(r);
  });
}

private void testCollision(StackPane r) {
  //Loop through all stackPanes
  for (StackPane r2 : stackPanes) {
    if (r2 == r) //except r
      continue;
    //test intersection with r
    var intersect = r.getBoundsInParent().intersects(r2.getBoundsInParent());
    if (intersect) {
      //Style intersecting pane
      r2.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #6a5246");
      r.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #6a5246");

      Group g = new Group();
      g.getChildren().add(r);
      g.getChildren().add(r2);
      gp.getChildren().add(g);

      r.setLayoutX(r.getLayoutX() - deltaX);
      r.setLayoutY(r.getLayoutY() - deltaY);
    } else {
      //Unstyle
      r2.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #ffffff");
      r.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #ffffff");
    }
  }
}
```

(I've got rid of the `setOnDragegd` method, which would only be setting the `onMouseDragged` handler and defined a `testCollision` method specialized in assessing collisions with the pane being dragged)

You will still have a problem with the styling though, as you're re-doing it any time you detect one collision, whereas any pane could very well be intersecting with several other ones at any time...
That could be solved in 2 obvious ways :

1. Memorizing the known intersections, and updating them as a pane is being dragged, then assessing which panes should be colored
2. Re-testing every possible collision on every event by assessing each pane against every other one preceding it the `stackPanes` arrayList instead of the simple loop I offered here. *(viable only for small numbers of panes)*

But that could be for another question...